# Xubuntu 13.10 no login screen

Tags: ubuntu, login, xfce, xubuntu, login-manager

I am using the android app so I may not format the question properly. I'm using xubuntu 13.10 64 bit.

I had a problem recently with var permissions and I solved it like so

https://askubuntu.com/q/431080/116070

It worked. Now I have another issue that just popped up, maybe it's caused by var maybe not. I can't see the login screen. Xubuntu keeps loading, you know that blue loading screen.

Three services failed to start

[image]

How to debug and fix the problem?

Comment: Please note that I asked the same question on askubuntu, flagged it to be migrated here, no one migrated it, so It still there because ita not migrated yet nor I can delete it because im using the android app so there's no delete option.. I'm not cross posting but I can't access my pc to delete it and the mods on askubuntu aren't migrating it, no one is answering it there too

Comment: That image is very hard to read. Do you ever get a prompt? Which services failed to start? Is one of them lightdm? Did you try logging in and running `service lightdm restart`?

Comment: @terdon no it failed with sudo, without sudo also fails. I think I have to reinstall it via livecd because I can't connect to wifi from tty

Comment: @terdon I installed gdm, now I see the login screen but once logged in I can only see the mouse pointer with black screen, the acpi deamon failed btw I had the same error before, forget how to fix it, ill keep digging

Comment: This type of thing is usually related to your graphics card. Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/85695) for pointers.

Comment: @terdon http://askubuntu.com/questions/428512/my-graphic-drivers-are-gone could it be solved by following your previous answer?

Comment: I answered your [ubuntu.se] question but I still can't tell what's going on here since I can't really read that screenshot. Which services are failing to start?

Comment: @terdon acpi daemon and lightdm failed to start, the issue however seems to be solved after i removed lightdm and installed gdm, but I don't know for sure

Comment: If so, please post an answer explaining that and accept it so the Q can be marked as answered.

Comment: @terdon I'll do so once the issue on askubuntu is solved, i want to see if the too issues are related